# Why are my arrays returned blank from a method but the code works fine when running in the main-Method?

Tags: java, arrays, class, multidimensional-array, methods

I'm having following problem with my program.
It's a "connect four" Java console application.
When starting my program, I reset 3 things.

1. A multi-dimensional char array

`public final int rows = 8, columns = 8;`

`public char[][] board = new char[rows][columns];`

I reset it with a for-loop, overwriting every array field with the character '.', which is my default board texture.

```
    public char[][] resetBoard() {
        // for loops cycle through every array field
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                board[i][j] = '.';
            }
        }
        return board;
    }
```

2. An integer-array

   `public int[] nums = new int[columns];`

I reset it with a for-loop using the variable i, since I just need an array with the length of columns, which just counts up from 1. It is used so the user know which column he's choosing. Like in chess "A6" e.g., except without letters.

```
    public int[] resetNums() {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            nums[i] = i + 1;
        }
        return nums;
    }
```

3. An integer

   `public int roundCounter = 0;`

The integers keeps track of how many rounds there have been in the current game. I want it to be printed while playing.

```
    public int resetRoundCounter() {
        // Resetting Round Counter, by initializing it to 0
        return roundCounter = 0;
    }
```

I reset these looking like this:

```
        gameMain main = new gameMain();
        gameMode mode = new gameMode();
        gameCheck check = new gameCheck();

        main.board = main.resetBoard();
        main.nums = main.resetNums();
        check.roundCounter = check.resetRoundCounter();
```

My problem is when printing the game board, the nums-array and the round counter none seem to work.
The game board is just completely blank. The nums-array is only 0's and the round counter stays at 0.
When running the code in the main-method it worked better than running it through classes etc.

My print method:

```
    public void printBoard() {
        gameMain main = new gameMain();
        gameCheck check = new gameCheck();

        // Printing number array with space in between the elements
        for (int i = 0; i < main.nums.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(main.nums[i] + " ");
        }
        // Printing the round count next to the number array
        System.out.println("            Round " + check.getRoundCounter());

        for (int i = 0; i < main.rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < main.columns; j++) {
                System.out.print(main.board[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < main.nums.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(main.nums[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
```

I could really use some help, since I've been up all night. Originally due to how much fun I was having programming this, now it has become frustrating.

Thanks for reading and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think what is happening to you is related to the references of the objects you are using. You are mixing two different ways of working, I give you an example:

You can use the reference of 'roundCounter' and work on it:

```
public void resetRoundCounter() {
        // Resetting Round Counter, by initializing it to 0
        roundCounter = 0;
}
```

or you can return it, like this:

```
public int resetRoundCounter() {
        // Resetting Round Counter, by initializing it to 0
        return 0;
}
```

In the first case, you will have to call the function like this:

```
resetRoundCounter(); //this function changes the value of your variable.
```

In the second case, you will have to call the function like this:

```
roundCounter = resetRoundCounter();
```

You can choose the way you like to work but I recomend you not working with global variables especially working with methods. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Do it as

```
public void resetBoard() {
    // for loops cycle through every array field
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            board[i][j] = '.';
        }
    }
}

public void resetNums() {
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        nums[i] = i + 1;
    }
}

public void resetRoundCounter() {
    // Resetting Round Counter, by initializing it to 0
    roundCounter = 0;
}
```

Finally, call them as follows:

```
gameMain main = new gameMain();
gameCheck check = new gameCheck();
main.resetBoard();
main.resetNums();
check.resetRoundCounter();
```

I also recommend you follow [Java Naming Convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) e.g. `gameMain` should be `GameMain` and `gameCheck` should be `GameCheck`.